# How to do multiple file uploads from a block's form?

Tags: 7

In the hook_block_configure of my block, I'm defining the form for my block.  I want it to have multiple file uploads, so I'm using "cardinality", but the following code isn't working for me.  I only get the one file field.

```
$form['background_image'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('A Background Image'),
  '#description' => t('An image file.'),
  '#cardinality' => -1,
);
```

Any ideas?

I'm using Drupal 7.

Note: I don't want to just upload multiple files at once.  I want the user to be able to upload "one more file" or delete one of the existing ones.

Comment: You are going to need to use AJAX for this functionality. Check [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34229/file-upload-with-ajax#73582). Should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the '#cardinality' it's not a form attribute, I couldn't find on the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

But I could find it on the [field_multiple_value_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.form.inc/function/field_multiple_value_form/7).

I suggest you to take another approach and use the AJAX framework, I found a couple of guides ([guide_1](http://lovewithbug.com/technology/drupal/how-to-use-drupal-ajax-form-for-multiple-fields-with-add-more-concept/) and [guide_2](http://rapiddg.com/blog/use-ajax-support-multiple-item-values-custom-drupal-7-forms)) that might be helpful.